# Does this warrant many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm creating a db for PC components inventory. I got component, component type, count (how many of it there is) and manufacturer.

My question is mainly about type. To explain, lets take hard drives as an example.

Component: Hard Drive
Type: SSD or SATA
Manufacturer: Samsung, HP, WD

The count will differ depending on the different combinations you can make from the previous information.

As I have many components (monitors, CPUs, HDs...etc.) and many types for each component, does that mean I have many to many relationship?

Also, each manufacturer manufactures different components and accordingly different types of these components. Does this mean I have many to many relationship between manufacturers and types?

Finally, I can't understand how I can have just ONE model for Type. Types of HD are different that types for CPUs or batteries! Should I split Type class into multiple classes for each component?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, for relationship between `Component` and `Type`, I don't think it is many to many relationship. It suppose to be one to many relationship because one storage drive for example can only be SSD or HDD, but not both. The business logic here is
"One `Type` can be assigned to many `Component`, but every `Component` is only one `Type`."

Secondly, you do not need to make a relationship directly between `Manufacturer` and `Type`. Indeed `Manufacturer` and `Type` relationship is actually many to many, but we have a natural bridge Entity here which is you guess it; `Component`! One `Manufacturer` will be making many `Component`, but one `Component` is only been manufactured by only one `Manufacturer`. And the same apply for other side of entity `Component` relationship to the `Type`. One `Component` is only `Type`, but one `Type` can have many `Component` associated to it.

Lastly, you don't need to create different class of `Type` for data storaga or monitor or CPU or any other `Component`. Sharing a single `Type` class will do its job perfectly. This way you can dinamically add your `Component` and `Type` associated with it without the nees to manually add new classes.